# botframework confirm dialog, send message as user

Tags: c#, dialog, botframework

I have created a confirm dialog where the user can select yes/no

```
 private async Task Confirm(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
        {
            var res= await result;
            await context.PostAsync(res? "Proceed" : "Ok then");
            if (res) {
                ......
            }
        }
```

If the user selects Yes he will receive the message "Proceed"
At the same time (again if "res" is true), i want to send a 
specific message to the bot without appearing in the conversation.
Is there a way to send a custom message back to the bot when user
press Yes?

Comment: Why do you want to send a message to the bot? You are developing the bot code, and during this if statement you are exactly where you want to do something. So do it there

Comment: Its an AI bot so I need to send a specific text in order for it to reply with the desirable text. In this if statement I need to build that text and send it to the bot imitating the user. I need something like imBack action of Hero Cards

Comment: What AI is behind? If it's LUIS, or QnAMaker, you can do it without trying to fake a message

Comment: No it is a custom AI that is still in the development mode to which I only send and receive messages. For now a fake message is my only option. If there is no way to do this by a confirm dialog then I will try a different solution

Comment: I do not know about the C# API, but in NodeJS API, there is an API `UniversalBot.receive` which can mimic bot receiving some event, you can look something similar in .NET API. https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.universalbot.html#receive

Answer (score 0):

You could try constructing a new activity using data stored in the `context` which you have access to in this method.  I don't fully understand your scenario but it seems this may work for what you need.

```
var a = new Activity();
a.Conversation = context.Activity.Conversation;
a.Recipient = context.Activity.Recipient;
a.From = context.Activity.From;
a.Id = context.Activity.Id;
...    //set whatever else you need set
a.Text = "Whatever you need the text to be";

//send or process the activity do what it is you are trying to accomplish
```

Edit: I think what you are actually looking for is [`Prompt.Confirm()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.promptdialog.confirm?view=botbuilder-3.12.2.4).

Comment: Could you tell me what you did not understand? Maybe I can try to explain better. I do not need to create a new activity. Can I use the same activity, change only the text and send it directly back to the bot. I need something like the PostBack action type of a HeroCard where you can sent back to the bot a text

Comment: See my edit, a prompt may work for what you need also